# Resize all image icons in two dimensional image array

Tags: java, image-resizing, image-manipulation, imageicon

I could just manually resize the images in my file folder, but obviously that would take way more work. So instead, I've been trying to resize my icons using getImageWidth() and getImageHeight(), but everything I tried so far just leads me to a compiler error. I would appreciate any help since I've been stuck on this issue for a few hours now.

```java
private void loadImages () {
        images = new Image[14][4];
        for (int suit = 0; suit <= 3; suit++) {
            String str = suits[suit];
            for (int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++) {
                String s = String.format("%s/%s_%d.png",CARDSET, str, rank);
                images[rank][suit] = new ImageIcon(s).getImage();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code you put in your question doesn't have anything to do with resizing. Please [edit] it and put the code you are complaining about. Also, add the compilation error that you are complaining about, and mark where in the code the line it says is wrong is located.

Comment: @RealSkeptic This part of the code is where I'm storing my images into a 2D image array and where I would manipulate my images to resize them. I'm just unsure how to do that. I tried doing `images[rank][suit] = new ImageIcon(s).getImage().getScaledInstance(70, 70, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);` beforehand and it just made my images disappear entirely on my JFrame, and when I tried to use getImageWidth() or getImageHeight() in place of getScaledInstance() my compiler just says it cannot find the method.